# Scala groupBy on case class object

Tags: java, scala

I want to group by on class instance(object)

// Below code fails to compile

```
  case class Employee(name:String,division:Int)

    val employees = List(Employee("Sumeet",1),Employee("Mahesh",2),Employee("Rhoit",1),Employee("Nexus",2))

     def groupByEmployee(list:List[Employee]):Map[Employee,List[Employee]] = {
        list groupBy(_)
      }

groupByEmployee(employees)
```

// But this works when i use specific attibute

```
case class Employee(name:String,division:Int)

val employees = List(Employee("Sumeet",1),Employee("Mahesh",2),Employee("Rhoit",1),Employee("Nexus",2))

 def groupByEmployee(list:List[Employee]):Map[Int,List[Employee]] = {
    list groupBy(_.division)
  }

groupByEmployee(employees)
```

Comment: Have you tried `list.groupBy(identity)` - Also, it would be good if you could explain why it doesn't compile, which error do you see?

Comment: HashMap(Employee(Mahesh,2) -> List(Employee(Mahesh,2)), Employee(Rhoit,1) -> List(Employee(Rhoit,1)), Employee(Nexus,2) -> List(Employee(Nexus,2)), Employee(Sumeet,1) -> List(Employee(Sumeet,1))): Map[Playground.this.Employee,List[Playground.this.Employee]]

Comment: identity gives all different

Comment: And that is the expected behaviour, it groups by things that are equal, there aren't any repeated elements in your sample. You didn't explain what do you want to achieve, what is your expected output.

Comment: does identity  works on has code

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean? `identity` is the identity, it is basically the same as `x => x`. But returning to my previous question, what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupBy` takes a function that returns the value to group by. `_.division` is Scala short hand for `(x) => x.division`

If you want to group by the *identity* of a case class instance (e.g, `Employee("Sumeet", 1)` and `Employee("Sumeet", 1)` group together, but `Employee("Sumeet", 2)` does not), then you'd want to use `hashCode` in your groupBy. E.g., `groupBy(_.hashCode)`

Comment: If you want the identity use the `identity` no need to call `hashcode`.

Comment: hashCode is probably the wrong approach here. Different objects should have different hashCodes, but objects with the same hashCode aren't necessarily the same object.